# $z=x=y$ in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, surfaces

It is a simply question. But I want to make sure. The surface $$z=x=y$$ represents  a line in $\Bbb R^3$ that passes  through the origin. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~:~x=y=z\}$ is a line passing through the origin and the point $(1,1,1)$ and can be rewritten as $\{(t,t,t)~:~t\in \Bbb R\}$ or as $\text{span}\{(1,1,1)\}$ and is a one-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: @JMoravitz, I am kind of confused little bit , Is it the same if we just say $x=y$ in $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: No.  The set $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~:~x=y\}$ is a plane and is $\{(t,t,s)~:~t,s\in\Bbb R\}$ is $\text{span}\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is a two-dimensional subspace.  It is the plane which includes the origin as well as the points $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz, Yes, you are right . Thank you so much.

Comment: Why are you calling it a *surface* if it's a line, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the your surface $S=\lbrace(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x=y=z \rbrace$ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ a basis for $S$ is $\beta=\lbrace (1,1,1)\rbrace$ therefore your $S$ is a line that pass throught of $(1,1,1)$. As @JMoravitz say.